# Bluetooth, audio, screenshot, camera stopped working on Lenovo Tab P11 Plus

Tags: bluetooth, audio, camera, android-11, lenovo

So this problem started happening 3, 4 days ago. On my Lenovo Tab P11 Plus none of the following functions are working. It has Android 11.

**Bluetooth**
The icon is lit/turned on but it is not working. When I long press and go to Bluetooth settings then it shows that Bluetooth is disabled but icon is turned on.

**Audio**
Audio icon is turned on but no audio coming from speakers. When I go to settings then all volume controls are disabled.

**Camera**
As soon as I open camera I get message `Can't connect to camera please make sure to close other apps that may cause camera or flashlight error`

**Screenshot**
When trying to take screenshot I get message `Taking screenshots isn't allowed by the app or your organization`

When I boot device then after Lenovo screen, another screen is shown which says 'Online Customization'. I am not sure this screen used to show up when I bought the tablet.

[image]

[image]

Did factory reset but no luck. Is my tablet infected with some kind of malware or is it hardware issue and gone for good? Or may be some issue with Android 11?

Comment: How old is the tablet and did you buy it as a new/unused device from a known vendor?

Comment: It's a used tablet. Bought it 5 months ago and it was working fine until few days ago.

Comment: Some manufacturer offer companies the possibility to remotely manage their devices in a way that even a factory reset does not releases the device from the management. If the device is then stolen the company can lock it or make other things with it remotely. This can happen at any time later. Not sure if Lenovo offers such a service but and I don't know if this is the feature that causes your problems but it seems to be reasonable.

Comment: Curious about the number below the Lenovo logo... can you go into the home screen, or is it stuck on the "Online Customization" screen? As Robert has mentioned, this might be something related to remote MDM (Mobile Device Management). On the other hand, I have a suspicion that the device might not be a real Lenovo Tab P11, but a faked one (e.g. booting animation edited). That's why I'm curious if it's possible to install an app to check device info, like [CPU-Z](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cpuid.cpu_z)

Comment: CPU-Z is showing that this is a genuine as it has same CPU and no. of cores plus other things as mentioned on GSM Arena page. Is it possible to root/flash this device like completely installing a new Android OS?